# How can I Open a Page in Modal Window in Sharepoint 2010 through Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, modal-dialog

I want to open a custom page to be opened in a modal dialog instead of new page.

Answer (score 2):

below is the script

```
function popUp()
{   
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.title = "Title";
options.width = 800;
options.height = 450;   
options.allowClose = true;
options.showClose = true;   
options.url = "/SubSite/SitePages/pageName.aspx;
options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);   
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
function CloseCallback(){}
```